# Trouble making my image centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble making the first image going centered. It stretches on the right side, but the left side seems to still have that sort of padding. I changed the padding in the layout file for the bootstrap to 0 but to no avail. Am I missing something really simple ? I thought container fluid allows to make the image full width. Included a screenshot.

Edit: I am using ASP.net mvc with bootstrap.

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Digital Systems Malaysia";
}


<a id="Home"></a>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Digital Systems Malaysia</h1>

</div>


<div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0;";>

        <img src="/Content/Images/background3.jpg";>
</div>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghPwN.jpg)

**EDIT IMPORTANT**

If anyone else is having this issue, do note that this is because of the MVC structure. The @RenderBody part is enclosed in a special div of class .body-content

That body-content class will automatically put a margin to your whole page and cannot be overwritten in the page itself. As such, if you want to remove the margin, you will have to either edit the class  or use absolute positioning for place something without taking into consideration the .body-content margin.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with the same issue.

Comment: See [Centering Things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) and [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) and [How to Center in CSS](http://howtocenterincss.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
text-align:center;
```

Attribute to the parental div of the image

Comment: Still the same =(  

This is bothering me so much. I just want the image to span across the screen like the header

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to put 
`

```
<div class="center">
<div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0;";>

        <img src="/Content/Images/background3.jpg";>
</div>
</div>
```

'

or

'

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0;";>
<center>
        <img src="/Content/Images/background3.jpg";>
</center>
</div>
```

'

or

you can edit container-fluid in the css file

Comment: The first 2 doesn't change anything. What changes would you make to the container-fluid in the css ? 

Currently it is 


.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

Comment: can you try any to put any value on these  .container-fluid { margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;}?

Comment: delete the auto an 0px value..just put any value to see whether it changes your interface or not. just try

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case. I tried 500px. The image does not react in any way. 

Then 100px. Still the same. 

:/   

My image size is 1920x 890

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the image itself overflows
You should also give the `img` a style to limit the width, otherwise it will display in full size.

```
img { width:100%; height: auto; }
```

Comment: I actually want it to be full width. As in, it covers the whole screen width. But right now, it stretches to the right, while leaving a white space to the left.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add the **bootstrap** class `text-center` to your div with the class `container-fluid`

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center" style="width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0;";>

    <img src="/Content/Images/background3.jpg";>
</div>
```

Comment: The picture is still the same :/

Comment: so, if I don't misunderstand you want to have this image as the background of your div class am I right ? you can try the background property with the path to the image

Comment: Are you referring to adding this  " background-image: url(/Content/Images/background3.jpg); "   to the .container-fluid ?

Comment: background-image: url('../Content/Images/background3.jpg'); 


Is that the right syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work by adding `style=" margin-left:-385px;`  to the image itself.

I however think there should be a better way to do this ... but if someone has the same problem as me, this is a fix that is working for me.